# @WebFilter is not processed in my Glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish-3, servlet-filters

I have a filter in my code with below settings..  I mapped everything in the value request

```
@WebFilter(value="/*",  dispatcherTypes={DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        logger.info("Inside init of MyFilter");
    }
}
```

My web.xml configuration is declared like this

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

When deployed to Glassfish 3.1.2, I checked the server logs during startup but even my init method is not called.  No errors or exception is being called also.

Anyone has idea how to troubleshoot?

Comment: try to change `value="/*"` into `value="*"`

Comment: 1) Try implement `doFilter` method and see what happens when you invoke your Web application. 2) Check log levels; change to `System.out.println`. 3) Pay attention to Java EE 6 tutorial: "Use the value attribute when the only attribute on the annotation is the URL pattern; use the urlPatterns attribute when other attributes are also used." HTH

Comment: oops...I implemented doFilter..I just remove it here just to shorten the code... I am thinking that if my init is called then my doFilter should be called but it is not the case... I will edit it again

Comment: @Daniel: `*` is not a valid URL pattern.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)

> Use the @WebFilter annotation to define a filter in a web application.
>   This annotation is specified on a class and contains metadata about
>   the filter being declared. The annotated filter must specify at least
>   one URL pattern. This is done by using the urlPatterns or value
>   attribute on the annotation. All other attributes are optional, with
>   default settings. **Use the value attribute when the only attribute on
>   the annotation is the URL pattern; use the urlPatterns attribute when
>   other attributes are also used.**

As your annotation has more attributes you should use the "urlPatterns" attribute instead of "value"